# SQL Server 2008 Synonym <name> refers to an invalid object

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, synonym

I am trying to call a stored procedure from SSIS.

One line of the code is

```
select *
FROM dbo.syn_tab_myTable
```

I can actually see this `dbo.syn_tab_myTable` sitting in my `Synonyms` folder. However, I've got following error:

> Error: 0xC002F210 at SQL Build tab_Stats, Execute SQL Task: Executing
>   the query "build.proc_build_stats ?" failed with the following error:
>   "Synonym 'dbo.syn_tab_myTable' refers to an invalid object.". Possible
>   failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set
>   correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established
>   correctly.

Then I just started a new query that I do the `select` operation again, but still I got this:

> Msg 5313, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Synonym 'dbo.syn_tab_myTable'
>   refers to an invalid object.

There are other synonyms in the same folder, while some of them appear in the drop list when I type the name, and some of them don't.

I have no idea what is causing this problem. Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Something has happened to the object referenced by the synonym. Run this:-

```
SELECT *  FROM sys.synonyms WHERE name = 'syn_tab_myTable'
```

and check the base_object_name column in the output, then check that the object that is being referenced still exists.

Comment: Urm.. okay.. so what if it definitely does?

Started getting this error after some database reshuffling for one table.

I've dropped and recreated the synonym... it's baffling.

Comment: I wonder whether you lost some permissions on the referenced object because of the reshuffling. (Though if you have dropped and recreated with correct permissions we may never know:-)

Comment: This still did not work properly. Pull in column names and not the data.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the synonym, select drop and create, then carefully review the script.  I had fat fingered mine, and while it created a synonym, the view it was looking for wasn't there.  I fixed the script, re-ran, now life is good again.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct, make sure you are connected to the right server and database. Right click on the database where synonyms exist, select new query and then type your syntax. You are getting an invalid object, because that object does not exist on the server/database that you are connected too.

The other answer `SELECT *  FROM sys.synonyms WHERE name = 'syn_tab_myTable` is also valid. Furthermore you can issue

```
SELECT *  FROM sys.synonyms
```

to see all the synonyms on your connected database and where they are pointing which can be quite useful.